# How to make a jQuery tooltip appear when hovered or clicked?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to produce a tooltip on a class called tool-tip-k on hover:

```
$(".tool-tip-k").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer').attr('title', 'Requires a King.');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','auto');
});
```

But there is a delay before it appears and I cannot work out how to remove it so thought I would also make the tooltip appear when it's clicked.  I tried this:

```
$(".tool-tip-k").click(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer').attr('title', 'Requires a King.');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','auto');
});
```

But it didn't work, in fact nothing appeared to but if I put console.log('test') into the second function, it did show test.

I can't work it out and need it either

1. showing immediately on hover or
2. On click

Comment: is this a custom tooltip function or are you using a plugin?

Comment: Why not just apply the attribute and CSS to the element at all times? The `title` doesn't appear except when you hover, and the cursor doesn't change except when you hover, so changing the CSS and attribute with JS is redundant.

Comment: Taking a step back... Relying on the browser's behavior of creating a tooltip from the `title` attribute is generally not ideal.  You have no real control over it, it's not particularly accessible, etc.  There are tooltip plugins you can use, or write your own.  In either case, you'd want the tooltip itself to be actual markup on the page that's positioned to appear as a tooltip.  (And include relevant aria attributes for accessibility.)